# Why Is My PCIe NIC Disabled?

Tags: networking, 13.04, server, ethernet

I've installed a card with two Intel 82576 ethernet ports into my PCIe expansion slot. 
I'm running Ubuntu server 13.04 amd64 with the 3.10 generic stable kernel.

When I run `lspci | grep Ethernet` I get the response:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82576 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

`Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V` is the onboard port, and its working just fine. The other two ports are the ones on the expension card.

When I run `lshw -class network` The response tells me that the two ethernet ports in question are `DISABLED`. The Configuration sub-section for the Intel 82576 ports show:

```
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.0.3-k firmware=1.80, 0x61520001 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

I have a cable plugged into one of the ports on the card, and I'm able to see connectivity LEDs blinking away during BIOS post.

When I open `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`it shows only the on board ethernet interface and neither of the interfaces on the expansion card.

I was using this card in a previous machine that was also running Ubuntu Server 13.04 and I was able to light it up without and problems.

How do I enable my NIC?

Comment: That says it has no link, not that it is disabled.  Plug it in.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig -a | grep Link` and `sudo ethtool eth1` and replace `eth1` with the port you are using. Also include the output of `dmesg | grep e1000e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk)**

After running the command `ifconfig -a | grep Link` I got the response:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:b9:64:ea
          inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:feb9:64ea/64 Scope:Link
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
p1p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e2:ba:15:5a:34
p1p2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e2:ba:15:5a:35
```

I then found this article after a quick Google search: [Ubuntu 12.10: renaming ethernet interfaces from “p1p1″ to “eth0″](http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2012/12/ubuntu-12-10-renaming-ethernet-interfaces-from-p1p1-to-eth0/)

I named one of the Intel 82576 interfaces eth1, and left the on-board interface as eth0.

After a reboot I did a `ifconfig eth1 up` and its fully functional!

I don't know why the two Intel 82576 interfaces were set up as p1p1 and p1p2, some further research is required. For now, I'm happy to have it working again.